# JavaScript logging stack for debug purpose

Tags: javascript, dom-events, stack-trace, printstacktrace

I'm trying to create a runtime snapshot of all the JavaScript function calls. For that I stumbled upon stacktrace.js. It seems to find and log about my custom events but I can't find any other function calls or JavaScript events otherwise in my JavaScript console.

I want to view this information without having any breakpoint in console. Just want to know if Stacktrace.js is working as expected or is there something that I'm missing here.

Also any comprehensive alternate would be much appreciated.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to collection information on _all_ function calls?